# If there is a statement that is only true on a condition, what does it say about when the condition evaluates false?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, if $a<b$ if $c>0$ then $ac < bc$.

That much is correct, but what does it say about when c is not greater than zero? Does it mean that ac is not less than bc? (I know that in the above example it can be very easily shown that when c is not greater than zero the equation does not hold, but does this rule hold globally, on all such conditions?).

Comment: In general if you have that an implication of the form "if $p$, then $q$"is true, then you know nothing about the truth of its inverse, that is, "if not $p$, then not $q$". You *do* know, however, that the *contrapositive* is true: "if not $q$, then not $p$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if

$$
A \text{ and } B \text{ implies } C
$$

it is *not* always true that

$$
A \text{ and } (\text{not } B) \text{ implies } (\text{not } C)
$$

For example, if a venomous snake that's orange in color bites you, you will die. It is not true that if a venomous snake that's purple in color bites you, you will not die.

The example works because color is an irrelevant detail. You can't conclude what you want to conclude because $B$ might be an irrelevant detail (here $c > 0$ happens to be relevant, but you don't know that *a priori*).